# Not able to open a site collection after migrating the web application to a new server

Tags: 2013

I am working on migrating a webapplication to a new server. I am using the approach of content database attach and detach. I am able to open some pages on the new server but not able to open some pages and libraries and site collections. Somebody please help.

Comment: Hi ALL                                                        Actually I am able to view the site collection in central admin but that is not loading completely.Its subsites are loading but parent site is not loading .Not getting any error in ULS.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please give us more details about the issue/ error, what error you are getting?

Couple of things to check / try.

- try to detach and reattach the content database using powershell
- From central admin> application management > view all site collections > on this page check if all site collections listed here...compare with source farm
- or you can count the number of site collections from both farm, central admin > application management > manage content database
- make sure all the solutions(if any) installed on the new server
- Check the ULS logs/ Application Logs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have any custom webparts deployed in those pages. If so, you need to deploy the solution there. Better if you can provide a screenshot or the ULS logs with much information.